# What does ": $['string'---]" do in Bash?

Tags: bash

I can't figure out what the "`: $['string'---]`" portion of this bash script is doing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
R=`tput lines` C=`tput cols`;: $[R--] ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$[R--]` is the deprecated equivalent of this arithmetic expansion:

```
$(( R-- ))
```

That is,

- it outputs the *current* value of `$R` (interpreted as a number)
- and *afterwards* decrements `$R`'s value (decreases its value by 1).

Answer (score 2):

Deprecated [arithmetic expansion syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith).